# Call Stored Procedure Repeatedly for version comparison

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables, openrowset

SSMS: 2008 R2

We are having our software system updated, which may contain an unknown number of undocumented changes to the way data is entered and stored in our database. We have asked for documentation, but only have schema compares for "physical" changes to the database, not the way the data is treated. They may change in the future, but for now we have to assume not.

In order to check that our stored procedures work as expected after the update, we would like to run a sample of procedures using a sample of parameters before and after the update to compare the actual data results. The stored procedures here all take a single Id as the parameter (they are used to make SSRS reports within the software system)

I have set some things up, but I am having problems with my approach and would welcome any suggestions about either a better way to do things, or how to fix my approach. The problem is that an error is returned whenever a called stored procedure uses a temporary table. Here is what I have done:

Made a script to get a random sample of Ids for paramaters (only one table used at the moment - that's fine).

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UpdateValidation_GET_RandomIdSample](@TestSizePercent DECIMAL(6,3))
AS
-- This table is already created and will persist both sides of the update
--CREATE TABLE Live_Companion.dbo.UpdateValidationIds
--( Id          INT IDENTITY(1,1)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
-- ,MyTableId   NT               NULL)

IF @TestSizePercent > 100 RAISERROR('Do you even percent, bro?',16,1)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(255)
TRUNCATE TABLE UpdateValidationIds

SET @SQL =
'INSERT dbo.UpdateValidationIds(Id)
SELECT TOP ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@TestSizePercent) + ' PERCENT ID FROM Live.dbo.MyTable ORDER BY NEWID()'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Made a second script to run a stored procedure for each Id in the table:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UpdateValidation_GET_ProcedureResultsManyTimes](@Procedure_Name VARCHAR(255))
AS

--DECLARE @Procedure_Name VARCHAR(255) = 'Live_Companion.dbo.MyProc'

DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @GET_ID CURSOR
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @MyTableId INT
DECLARE @FirstRun BIT = 1
SET @GET_ID = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Id FROM Live_Companion.dbo.UpdateValidationIds
    WHERE MyTableId IS NOT NULL
OPEN @GET_ID
FETCH NEXT FROM @GET_ID INTO @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @MyTableId = MyTableId FROM Live_Companion.dbo.UpdateValidationIds
    WHERE Id = @ID

    IF @FirstRun = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO #ProcedureOutput FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',''Server=SQL1;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',''EXEC ' + @Procedure_Name + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@MyTableId) + ''');'
        SET @FirstRun = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        INSERT #ProcedureOutput SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',''Server=SQL1;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',''EXEC ' + @Procedure_Name + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@MyTableId) + ''');'
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM @GET_ID INTO @ID
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + '
SELECT * FROM #ProcedureOutput
DROP TABLE #ProcedureOutput'
EXEC (@SQL)

CLOSE @GET_ID
DEALLOCATE @GET_ID
```

So now I should be able to execute the second procedure for various stored procedures and output the results to file over a range of Ids, then repeat using the saved (initially random) Ids again after the update and compare the results.

The trouble is, it fails when any of the called procedures use a temporary table:
EDIT:
Error Message returned:

> Cannot process the object "EXEC Live_Companion.dbo.MyProc 12345". The
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" indicates that
>   either the object has no columns or the current user does not have
>   permissions on that object.

Any suggestions or ideas for how to proceed?

Comment: Could you perhaps also post the error details?

Comment: I have done, @Geewers - good point!

Comment: Try and wrap the logic of `Live_Companion.dbo.MyProc` inside a View and then `SELECT` from the View instead of executing a Stored Procedure. Something like `''SELECT * FROM ' + @View_Name + ' WHERE MyTableId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@MyTableId) + '''`

Comment: Nice idea - unfortunately, however, the point of the test is to check whether changes to the data will affect the existing stored procedures, so I would ideally like to be able to use the stored procedures in an unchanged state (which makes the test more reliable), rather than testing a view or a changed procedure, which might react differently to the changes.

Comment: Is `Live_Companion` name of your current database or is it referring to another one? If it is current database, try removing it from your code. If it refers to another database, check your user permissions or connection to that database.

Comment: The procedures above are run in the Live_Companion; the only reason `OPENROWSET()` was used was to get the information into a temporary table (in turn, so that the column list would be dynamic). I have just tried removing the database name from the `@Procedure_Name`, but it caused a "could not find procedure called MyProc" type error (there is more than one database on the server).